# Debugging Visual Studio 2017 :Chrome script debugging is enabled

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to run web App on Chrome but I am getting this message

[image]

> Chrome script debugging in Visual Studio is enabled

after that application starts but I am not able to debug

I trying to enable debugging

[image]

I tried to put breakpoints but this is not working

I also performed following steps

1. Delete ASP.NET temporary files from 
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
   Files

   2 Change build configuration to debug from project properties.

   3 Delete bin folder from your project.

   4 Check if compilation debug is set to true in the web.config

   5 iisreset

   6 Rebuild the project.

I am not able to get any relevant answer for the problem .

is it anyone facing similar problem

I try to google but only official site have some documentation about it . which is very confusing

Need some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it by following these steps inside Debug -> Options ->Debugging->General->Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET(Chrome and IE) you can disable it. 
[image]